# Two VLC Apps in AppCenter

Tags: applications, appcenter, vlc

There are 2 VLC apps appeared when I searched "vlc" in appcenter. The first one i think i installed months ago. The second one is more updated and is not installed.

[image]

---

And why is the uninstalled one over 700 MB?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One is from **eos** and the other is from **Flatpak** repository